# Android: Making EditText similar to Chrome's URL box

Tags: android, textbox, android-edittext

I'm making chatting application for my school's assignment.

In my opinion, the default EditText in Android does not looks good. I want to make it looks like the URL box in Android's Chrome:

[image: Chrome's EditText]

I have seen this design used in other applications such as [Catch Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threebanana.notes&hl=en) (which looks beautiful).

So, is there any built-in option to change the EditText or we must draw it from scratch? Can anyone give link? I tried googling it, but I don't know the correct term

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blindly use below layout style..
You will have your layout ready. Just replace the button backgrounds and your are done.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip">
        <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Type URL"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Refresh"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn1"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Backround transparent seems to be the easiest way to achieve this, even though it is not exactly the same, but close enough. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[image]you can achieving this by doing edittext background transparent.

so put your image in background of your layout and take a edittext inside this. and make edittext transpernt..

or 
try this

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/tracknumbertxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/info"
        android:background="@drawable/enter_tracking_no"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Tracking No."
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"

        android:singleLine="true" >

    </EditText>
```

here i have assign padding left..

so as per your design you have to set paddingRight property instead of paddingLeft..

Comment: Thanks, but what is imeOptions for? it does not seem to have any effect

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing native to the SDK that can make it look like that. (maybe if you restrict use to only a certain version of the OS, then you can use that version's default styling, but isn't really a viable solution)

You will need to create an image to use as a background for the EditText to make it look how you want. The best options for text boxes and things like that are to either use a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) [image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517693/how-does-a-9patch-png-work-in-android-apps), or to create a [layer-list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211929/styling-edittext-view-with-shape-drawable-to-look-similar-to-new-holographic-the) file and describe your design that way. Either way, the file would go in the res/drawable folder in the project and you would set it as the background like so:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/et_whatever"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    background="@drawable/YOUR_FILE_NAME" />
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm restricting for ICS+ only. So I guess I'm okay with background: transparent
9 Patch image seems interesting, I will give it a try sometimes