# How to make custom button with only center area stretched in Android?

Tags: android, button

I need help with a custom button in Android. I want to make a button which exists of three components: a left border, a right border and the center.

[image: Left border image] [image: Center image] [image: Right border image]

If the button is stretched horizontally, the right and left borders must stay intact, and the center must be stretched.

I tried to make it using the Android GUI editor in Eclipse, but it didn't succeed. Now is there a way to achieve this? If yes, how? Do I need to use an `ImageButton` or a `Button`?

Comment: You can use 9 patch image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517693/how-does-a-9patch-png-work-in-android-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called nine patch or 9patch.
Here is the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) and [here also](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).
And there is a simple tool to create 9patch made by [Roman Nurik](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html).

Comment: this is from Step 1 if you have android-sdk in your computer. 

From a terminal, launch the draw9patch application from your SDK /tools directory.

Comment: @MCEmperor more docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: @Spurdow don't post links that are already in the answer. It's useless

Comment: Ah, what you guys mean is that Android **recognizes the image being a 9patch image automatically** if the filename ends with .9.png. That makes sence; it works.

Comment: @MCEmperor yes exactly ;)

Comment: @SimonMarquis oh ok sorry bout that.

Answer (score 0):

// Use Android asset Studio for generate 9 patch image.

// Under Stretch region you can select stretchable area

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Comment: @ MC Emperor. There is another tab for padding for 9 patch image. No need to install android sdk.