# How to set Different Key Background for every Key in Android Custom Keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am Working on a Custom Keyboard and I need to set different image for each key at runtime or dynamically but I am not getting how to do this.

I am using this code:

```
<com.keyboard.KeyBoard.LatinKeyboardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.keyboard.KeyBoard"
android:id="@+id/keyboard"
android:keyBackground="@drawable/black_bg" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

and now i want to get `android:keyBackground="@drawable/black_bg"` attribute in:

```
@Override 
public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    super.onStartInputView(attribute, restarting);   
}
```

because i have to change image background here for keys dynamically but I am not getting how to do this.

Comment: I thinkthat a similar answer can be found here - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000543/customize-the-appearance-of-a-key

Comment: But i want to set background of keys instead of text i am not getting how to do this plz help me

Comment: The "key" here is the for loop: `for(Key key: keys)` - this thing will go through all the keys of the keyboard and you can set the key's icon (see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#icon), which is taken from here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html . I think that this is the only way of changing keys individually. Your method will change the background of all the buttons.

Comment: for a key its not possible because there is no constant background for the key..but you can set drawable images as a background for keys..for this you have to create different colours of drawables

Comment: @kalyanpvs how i can set in drawable actuly i have to set only one image ie. white image firset time when user will select black than all keys have black image in backgrount thats it can u please tell me

Comment: Keyboard keyboard = keyboardView.getKeyboard();
  List<Key> keys = keyboard.getKeys();
  HashMap<String, int[]> data = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
  for (Key key : keys) {
   if (Character.isLetter(key.codes[0])) {
    key.icon=your drawable image;

   }
  }

Comment: @Kalyanpvs u mean if (Character.isLetter(key.codes[0]))
         {
          key.icon= R.drawable.whitebg;
         }  but i am getting error on  key.icon= R.drawable.whitebg; line please tell me

Comment: Actually android framework doesn't provide us the ability to change a key background at runtime.If you want to achieve this (change skin, e.g.), you'll have to do most drawing work with your custom view.

Comment: Look my answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/39091883/4964307](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39091883/4964307) I hope to help you.

Answer (score 2):

There was a later duplicate question posted at 
[how to change key background of any key in Android soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714172/how-to-change-key-background-of-any-key-in-android-soft-keyboard/22454382#22454382) . It had some good answers.